# How to show country flag in navigation drawer menu instead of simple icon

Tags: android, image, icons

I want to show the flag of any country as a small image instead of showing the vector graphic in a navigation menu of a drawer. The image can be either jpg, png or any suitable format.

I am trying to show the images but i only get a ractangle filled with grey color instead of the original image. I have tried jpg, png and gif. I also tried to set their dimensions to 24x24 and 48x48.

Does any body have an idea how to achieve the following.

Following is the item code in xml file:

```
<item
android:id="@+id/english"
android:icon="@drawable/english"
android:title="English" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add This line in Java Code,

```
NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
navigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);
```

And if you want to change size of drawable, add below line in dimen.xml

```
 <dimen name="design_navigation_icon_size" tools:override="true">40dp</dimen>
```

Answer (score 0):

That part looks fine, there must be something else in your code causing it not to show the image.

Comment: the flag icon is shown in the left side pane for its corresponding xml tag but not shown  when the app is run. Instead only a dark rectangle

Comment: Now that you say that, I remember putting images in a nav drawer and it only seemed to work with transparent black and white images.  There is probably something in your AppTheme that you can change to make it show a normal image

Comment: <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/button</item>
    </style>

Comment: It appears that this will work:    yournavigationview.setItemIconTintList(null);
This should disable the the tinting